How to configure NIFI with ISTIO Service Mesh?
Error while load page on Browser: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error
I have deployed ISTIO version 1.14.0 and NIFI version 1.16.0 on Oracle Kubernetes cluster using helm
Below is my ISTIO Gateway configuration:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: istio-system
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-system
  name: gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingress
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: secret
      mode: SIMPLE 

Below is my NIFI virtual service configuration
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nifi
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: nifi
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: nifi-virtual-service
  namespace: nifi
spec:
  gateways:
  - ops-gateway
  hosts:
  - FQDN
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /nifi
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nifi-headless
        port:
          number: 8443

Istio Ingress logs:
"GET /nifi HTTP/2" 502 UPE upstream_reset_before_response_started{protocol_error} - "-" 0 87 5

Can someone share the ideas to resolve it?
Need to resolve below:
Error while load page on Browser: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error

Please ensure gateway name mentioned in virtual service is proper.  Its mentioned as below but it not matching with the gateway name created.  Also its better to create gateway in application namespace itself instead of istio-system namespace.
spec:
  gateways:
  - ops-gateway

Request you to map the hostname mentioned in gateway and virtualservice.  In the gateway its mentioned as "*" and virtual service as "- FQDN".  For more details kindly refer gateway and virtual service documentation.
In the gateway definition kindly change selector as below
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway


Thanks for your reply but the same gateway is working for other applications. but for NIFI it's giving errors as mentioned above

Please ensure the gateway and virtual service are tied properly with the corrections mentioned, so that istio will be able to route the requests to service.

Checked GW and VS is tied properly but no luck. :(

Please share updated / modified gateway and virtualservice yaml
